# Highlight menu item onclicl

Tags: javascript, jquery, menu, highlight

I have found several questions to this. I am trying to highlight a selected menu item.

The current code I am using is

```
<script src="JavaScript/jquery-1.10.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script>
function active_menu() {
    var url = window.location.href;
    $('.nav a').filter(function() {
        return this.href == url;
    }).addClass('current');
}
</script>
<!--Start Menu -->
  <ul id="nav">
      <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="runetable.php">Rune List</a></li>
      <li><a href="alpha.php">Runic Alphabet</a>
      <li><a href="trans.php">Runic Transliteration</a></li>
      <li><a href="aetts.php">The Aetts</a></li>
      <li><a href="runes.php">Runes</a>
          <ul>
          <li>Freya's Aett</li>
          <li><a href="fehu.php">Fehu</li>
          <li>Uruz</li>
          <li>Thurisaz</li>
          <li>Ansuz</li>
          <li>Raidho</li>
          <li>Kenaz</li>
          <li>Gebo</li>
          <li>Wunjo</li>
          <li>Hagal's Aett</li>
          <li>Hagalaz</li>
          <li>Nauthiz</li>
          <li>Isa</li>
          <li>Jera</li>
          <li>Eiwaz</li>
          <li>Perthro</li>
          <li><a href="algiz.php">Algiz</a></li>
          <li>Sowilo</li>
          <li>Tyr's Aett</li>
          <li>Tyr</li>
          <li>Berkana</li>
          <li>Ehwaz</li>
          <li>Mannaz</li>
          <li>Laguz</li>
          <li>Inguz</li>
          <li>Dagaz</li>
          <li>Othila</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      <li><a href="about.php">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>

<!-- End Menu -->
```

This code works... Sort of...
I have found maybe 5 or 6 examples and I have run into the same problem with all of them.

Items 2, 6, and 7 will not highlight. That would be Rune List, Runes, and About.

I do not understand why these entries will not highlight, no matter which solution I try. As I said, I have tried a few and they all work except for those menu items.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? I am going nucking futs trying to figure this out.

Thanks for reading!
Jim

Comment: Just a typo: `$('#nav a')`, not `$('.nav a')`

Comment: Unfortunately, that did not work. It is still only the three I mentioned earlier that do not function correctly.

Comment: Have you looked at what `window.location.href` returns? It's a full URL, whereas your `a` elements only have partial URLs. You might get better help if you complete your question with troubleshooting info

Comment: I added an alert just to see what is being returned. I am getting "localhost/runes.php" for example. That is one of the pages that does not highlight properly.. Strange thing though... If I go to one of the pages listed earlier as not working, I get an alert with that output. If I go to a page that has been working correctly, I do not get an alert at all...

Comment: You have malformed HTML for one of those links. Fehu doesn't have a closing </a>. Also Runic Alphabet doesn't have a closing </li>. Kinglish is also correct in that your jQuery selector is incorrect. You've defined nav as an ID so your selector should have #nav instead of .nav.

Comment: Thank you for the info. Unfortunately, that did not help the situation. I went through everything that I could, hell I even went through the CSS again to see if there was anything weird there. I cannot find any reason that only those three links do not highlight when clicked. They highlight on mouseover but not when active...